# check file permissions in php with windows authentication on iis

Tags: php, iis, iis-6, windows-authentication, php-5.4

I have an internal site built with php 5.4 on iis 6 using windows authentication. I set up file permissions so certain people can only access certain files.

I am trying to create a search function so users can search for a file on a site, but I only want to show users the files they are allowed to access.

How would I use php to check if the logged in user has permission to view a certain file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering how. I ended up using

```
$perm = is_readable($file)
```

to check if they had permission.

Make sure to have `fastcgi.impersonate = 1` set in php.ini